# REST/Python call to get Amazon Alexa answers

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I need to send a list of questions to be asked from Alexa, and get the responses in the form of text (not voice). The responses must be exactly the same as what the Alexa app provides. All the documentation/examples I've seen so far is for the case where the goal is to create a new Alexa skill which is not my goal.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me to an example or documentation for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi, perhaps try the [Alexa Voice Service](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-voice-service)?

Answer (score 0):

Alexa responses and requests are in a JSON format. It's easier to see the interaction when you're testing a skill so even though it's not your end goal it would probably be useful to create a dummy skill and test it in the alexa developer console.

If you're trying to make a chatbot type project you would create an API Gateway endpoint for your Alexa Skill's lambda function and then use that with dialogflow and its text based integrations such as messenger, web demo, twilio, etc.

Here is an example in the documentation of what a response and request looks like:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html